# Periodic junk on serial interface

Tags: uart, embedded

I have an embedded board, based on Allwinner V40, which has a serial (UART) interface at TTL voltage levels. I access this interface with a little adapter board (MAX232) and a RS232->USB adapter.

Normally, this interface is configured to send debug information (/dev/ttyS0 under linux). I can turn that on and off, and I can send and receive data as I want. However, something else sends data exactly every ten seconds. This is what the junk looks like (10 seconds between each line, recorded at 9600 baud, the third line has been sent by me).

[image]

For reference, this is the first line in hex:

```
0A 05 31 04 41 6C 4E 0A 02 39 02 F3 F0 F4 F7 F1 F1 F6 F3 F1 F6 F1 FF FF FF FE FF FF FF FF FF FF FF
```

I've tried changing the baud settings etc., in case something else is sending with a different baud rate, but that lead to nothing. I also attempted disabling Bluetooth, since Raspberry Pis have a similar problem when Bluetooth is enabled. That did not help, but it also does not get worse if Bluetooth is actively used.

This is a two-wire UART, there is no flow control. UART 0 is wired up to PB22 and PB23 on the SoC, which seems correct. From my sys_config.fex (I'm using the legacy/Allwinner kernel):

```
[uart0]
uart0_used       = 1
uart0_port       = 0
uart0_type       = 2
uart0_tx         = port:PB22<2><1><default><default>
uart0_rx         = port:PB23<2><1><default><default>

[uart0_suspend]
uart0_tx         = port:PB22<7><1><default><default>
uart0_rx         = port:PB23<7><1><default><default>
```

I'm hoping somebody recognizes the bit pattern and could tell me what causes it. Any ideas?

Comment: Is the watchdog enabled?

Comment: I don't know. To be honest, I'm not even sure what you are referring to...

Comment: `grep -R "HELLO THIS IS A TEST" /`

Comment: something like root@orangepizero:~# systemctl status watchdog.service

Comment: From what I could find, and this may not be helpful, but 0x0A 0x05 are ASCII control characters for "Newline" "Enquiry"... all the lines that begin that way are what you refer to as "junk"?  Could it be a method of flow control(?)    maybe you have blank lines in your file(?)  I don't know, just throwing out things that might correlate to other things you have discerned already.

Comment: @CapnJJ yes, all lines begin with 0x0A, 0x05, 0x31 (or 0x32), and end with lots of bits set (0xFF etc.). "HELLO THIS IS A TEST" was me, to prove that I have the same baud rate and can communicate :-) .

Comment: @SpehroPefhany This device has Android 6 (rooted), no systemctl. There is a watchdog timer in the SoC which can reset the device if it hangs, but we do not use it currently.

Comment: Ah. I assumed that when you wrote _"something else sends data every ten seconds. This is what it looks like"_, you showed the actual data that is sent every ten seconds. Silly me.

Comment: Looks like a flow control, valid data check issue not being filtered properly.  Do you      check UART error status and wish to filter results?

Comment: Maybe check with lsof /dev/ttyS0 if there is another process using the port?

Comment: @filo Bingo! It was a touchscreen daemon, `eGTouchD`, randomly opening all TTYs and writing to them. You had to use the command repeatedly to catch it in the act, though. If you make an answer with the lsof trick I can accept it so you can get the rep :-).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check with lsof /dev/ttyS0 if there is another process using the port?